# Ordered list with menu tag - reset numbering

Tags: html

I have a simple ordered list which in each has a menu tag and some list items such as:

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <h2>List item 1</h2>
        <menu>
            <li><a href="#">Action 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Action 2</a></li>
        </menu>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h2>List item 2</h2>
        <menu>
            <li><a href="#">Action 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Action 2</a></li>
        </menu>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Unfortunately with this markup, the numbering of the outer list items gets affected by the list items inside the menu.

So the second outer list item should be numbered 2 but infact it is numbered 4.

How can this be avoided?

Comment: That's because you're using `<menu>` instead of `<ul>` on your 2nd level. Does the `<menu>` tag even exist in html?

Comment: I think menu is valid since it is a menu of actions for that particular part of the content.

Comment: OneTrickPony is right, `<menu>` doesn't add a new level to the list as `<ul>` would do, therefore it won't behave like there is a 2nd level.

Comment: I know, but menu is more semantically correct.  I am wondering the best way to get these to play nice together

Comment: <nav> is the semantic element in HTML5 that would be used in this context. I'd be tempted to wrap the parent <ol> in a <nav> block if "List item 1" and "List item 2" are themselves part of the menu structure, or around the child <ol> elements if these are discrete and separate menus. In either case the nav would be used in addition to, not in place of, the <ol> or <ul>. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/nav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in some browsers. Chrome gets the numbering wrong, IE and Firefox get it right.

Fixing this with CSS would get a bit tricky, so it is best to use `ul` instead of `menu`. According to HTML 4.01 spec, the [`menu` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/lists.html#edef-MENU) is a deprecated element similar to `ul` but intended to be rendered as a menu list, but in practice browsers display it like `ul`. But as observed here, there is a bugs in the Chrome implementation – yet another reason to use `ul` instead of `menu`, as strongly recommended in the spec.

(HTML5 proposes to redefine `menu` in a complicated manner, making it even less suitable for a simple itemized list.)